# Setting PBS/Torque/qsub parameters in script via command line arguments

Tags: bash, pbs, qsub, torque

I want to be able to easily change how many `nodes`, `ppn`, etc I submit to `qsub` via script. That is, I want run somthing like this:

```
qsub script.sh --name=test_job --nodes=2 --ppn=2 --arg1=2
```

With a script like the following:

```
#/bin/bash
#PBS -N ${NAME}
#PBS -l nodes=${NODES}:ppn=${PPN},walltime=${WALLTIME}
#PBS -q ${QUEUE}
#PBS -m ${MAILOPTS}
#PBS -M ${EMAIL}

/some/command ${ARG1}
```

So, I want to be able to pass in arguments that both change the PBS environment as well as some that go to the executable itself.

I've tried using the `-v` argument of `qsub`:

```
qsub script.sh -v NAME=test_job,NODES=16,PPN=16,ARG1=2
```

But the job submitted with the name `script.sh` and 1 `node`, 1 `ppn`.

Any ideas on a solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@dbeer's answer gave me a little more insight. The solution to my problem is as follows:

`#PBS` args are overwritten by the command line. In such case, the args to PBS and the script itself must be separated. Therefore, rather than trying to do something like:

```
#PBS -l nodes=${NODES}:ppn=${PPN},walltime=${WALLTIME}

/some/command ${ARG1}
```

inside the script and running like

```
qsub script.sh -v NODES=2,PPN=2,WALLTIME=160:00:00,ARG1=2
```

these can all be set with args to `qsub` itself:

```
qsub script.sh -l nodes=2:ppn=2,walltime=160:00:00
```

Then, any args that need to be passed to the executable can be passed through the `-v` argument to `qsub`:

```
qsub script.sh -l nodes=2:ppn=2,walltime=160:00:00 -v ARGS1=2
```

Answer (score 4):

In Torque, all of the #PBS arguments are overridden when a matching argument is specified on the command line. For example, if your script has:

`#PBS -l nodes=2`

You can submit:

`qsub script.sh -l nodes=4`

and the command line will take precendence over the script. The docs have a [complete list](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-1-0/adminGuide/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qsub.htm%3FTocPath%3DAppendices%7CAppendix%2520A%253A%2520Commands%2520Overview%7C_____21) of the command line arguments.